# Ошибка при работе со слайдером из библиотеки JQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подключаю слайдер, до этого сайт уже был напичкан jquery, и тут слайдер не работает, а в консоле вообще куча ошибок, например:

> jquery is not defined

Посмотрите, пожалуйста, у меня фантазия на исходе http://tmhomes.pirogov.ru/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script src="/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"> </ script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/search.js"></script>
```

Порядок объявления неверный.
Зависимые библиотеки надо писать после основной. А у вас ниво.слайдер до джиквери, хотя ее пытается использовать. Поэтому и не пашет.